# android studio loads project differently

Tags: android, android-studio

I opened a previously saved gradle project and it loads differently unlike other android projects,

These are different projects, but android studio loaded it differently.
Any idea how to fix it.

one looks like the root folder view(like how it is in windows)
the other one is how it usually is when you start a project.

This is how it looks now.
[image: This is how my project looks like now,]

[image: This is how it should look like,]

this. is how it should look like.

Comment: is your gradle build failing?

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: @Grisu47, I had to rebuild the gradle and the issue was fixed, thanks